# How to create a new binary file and fill it with a constant value?

Tags: c++, file, visual-c++, io

I'm using `cstdio` functions to create an empty binary file and need it to be initialized to a specific byte value (can be zero, but not necessarily).

```
FILE* file = std::fopen("path/to/file", "wb+");
```

Is there a way to fill the whole file with a value, or is creating and filling a buffer and then using `std::fwrite` to continuously fill the file my only option? Something like

```
std::ffill(byteValue, sizeof(byteValue), fileSize, file);
```

It would be okay to have platform specific solutions (I'm targeting windows and linux).

Comment: 0 for linux is special, but in general you have to write all data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using C++ iostreams, it's pretty trivial:

```
std::ofstream out("path/to/file", std::ios::binary);

char byteValue = '\0'; // or whatever

std::fill_n(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(out), fileSize, byteValue);
```

If `fileSize` is really large, however, you may prefer to use `std::ofstream::write` instead--it can be substantially faster.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to mmap the file to memory and use memset on that memory. But filling a buffer and writing it multiple times to the file would be an easier solution and platform independent. The mmap and CreateFileMapping are platform specific.